# how to implement bootstrap 3 into a single-page in a huge enterprise app built on bootstrap 2.3.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i just want to know if i import bootstrap 3 on my page, would it just extend the bootstrap or would it cause a conflict in the bootstrap 2.3.1 page and issues occur when i go back to a 2.3.1 page?

```
<link href="bootstrap-3.1.0"/>
```

if so, is there a way around it by unloading css once route is not on my page any more?

My goal is to make my module responsive and not affect how the main application performs.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/